# How could I do the filter in recarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with data file named data.csv

```
name,value
A,10
1,20
B,30
3,20
...
```

So the problem is I use numpy with mlab to load this csvfile

```
data = mlab.csv2rec(data.csv)
```

I have a question, how could I filter out the `data.name is a number` ?

for example: the output should be

```
1,20
3,20
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter the recarray while preserving the structure of the filtered records:

```
filter_idx = [i for i, s in enumerate(data.names) if s.isdigit()]
data[filter_idx]
```

gives

```
rec.array([('1', 20), ('3', 20)], 
      dtype=[('names', 'S1'), ('value', '<i4')])
```

---

If you just want to print out the filtered records like in your example output I would just do it and catch the exceptions:

```
for rec in data:
    try:
        print int(rec.names), rec.value
    except:
        pass
```

prints

```
1 20
3 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [isinstance()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

```
for i in data:
    if isinstance(data.name, int):
        print data.name, data.value
```

or

```
new_data = list(x for x in data if isinstance(x.name, int))
```

works fine with this example:

```
data = [[1,10], ["a", 20], [2, 30], ["b", 40], [3, 50]]
new_data = list(x for x in data if isinstance(x[0], int))
print new_data
```

Comment: In a numpy recarray, all the values in the column are the same type.  This would only work if he is using object as the data type of the first field, which is not recommended, and almost certainly not what csv2rec returns by default.